# What does 'democratizing AI' exactly mean?

Tags: terminology, social, automated-machine-learning

In my AI literature research, I often notice authors use the term 'democratizing AI', especially in the AutoML area. For example in the abstract (last sentence) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06827):

> LEAF therefore forms a foundation for **democratizing** and improving AI, as well as making AI practical in future applications.

I think I have an idea of what this means, but I would like to ask you for some more specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular context, "Democratize" means to make more accessible to people.

Thus, "Democratizing AI" means to make AI softwares and AI programming available, accessible and easy to use for the vast majority of people.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that AI and other sciences have been seen as undemocratic since many resources (including physical resources like super-computers and intellectual resources like research papers) are controlled by universities, corporations, publishers, etc. with limited access for people in general. Among other reasons.